# Make Shared Drive unhidden by default for the group of people

Tags: google-drive-api

Due to [this limitation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/unhide#try-it), Shared Drive becomes automatically hidden for certain people. There is an [API](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9310461?hl=en) that allows one to make specific Shared Drive unhidden, but only for a personal account.

The task is to make this drive unhidden for a large group of people (considering myself being an admin/superadmin of Google Workspace).

Is there a way how to make it in an easy and elegant way? Or how do I set a global rule for the drive that it doesn't get hidden for users of a large group?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Hi there! I don't catch your original environment in order to understand your issue. As far as I can get, you have some shared drives in common with some users. Some of those shared drives are [hidden](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/hide), and you ask for a way to unhide them efficiently. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Hi! Yup, you're right :)

The whole idea is following: there is a shared drive we're trying to share with the Google Group that contains all the members of the company. This drive is hidden for some of the users (due to that limitation in the original post).

We're trying to find a way, how to unhide this drive for everyone in that Google Group.

Ideally - we want to make this drive unhidden by default.
I've filed a [feature request](https://www.cloudconnectcommunity.com/ccc/ls/community/googleworkspace-feature-ideas/post/6200210093375488#) on Google CCC as well.